# How to handle symmetric keys in Java web applications

Tags: java, security, encryption

What is the best of practice on safely handle symmetric keys in Java web applications?  Our current implementation stores encrypted data into the database, and encrypt/decrypt data using a symmetric key stored under a properties file.

Putting the symmetric key under a properties file doesn't seem like the right way to handle symmetric keys to me.

Comment: Are you asking about symmetric keys, or private keys? Not that it makes much difference, but you've contradicted yourself. The answer in both cases is a KeyStore.

Comment: I'll edit.  question is on symmetric keys.

Comment: what is the right way to handle passwords to keystore?

Comment: Aha, same question really. Ultimately this comes down to physical security of the server host: you have to lock it down physically and ensure you know who is accessing it, and when.